# Error when execute complex query builder with relation in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have complex query builder to get all image from images relation with images_tags table

```html
$tags = [1, 2, 3];
$items = ImagesTable::with(['images_tags' => function ($query) use ($tags) {
   $tags = $query->select('image_id', ImageTag::raw('count(tag_id) as total'))
          ->whereIn('tag_id', $tags)
          ->groupBy('image_id')
          ->having(['total', 3])
          ->get();
      return $tags;
    }])->get();
```

And two table

```html
(images)-(images_tags)  1-n
images (
  id int  
  title varchar(255) 
)
images_tags (
  id int  
  image_id,  
  tag_id int 
  constraints fk foreign key('image_id') on images('id')
)
```

But i get error

> ErrorException in Grammar.php line 58:
>   strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

And i found this line code cause error

```html
ImageTag::raw('count(tag_id) as total')
```

And i don't know why is this?

Comment: Can you try using  \DB instead of ImageTag. Or Try using \ before your ImageTag like \ImageTag. Try like these \ImageTag::raw('count(tag_id) as total')  OR \DB::raw('count(tag_id) as total')

Comment: Yeah. You're true, @manian ! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am glad that it worked. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] This question is solved!
I replaced ImageTag with \DB and it works.